# How to convert NSDate into Unix timestamp in Objective C/iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I convert an NSDate to a Unix timestamp in Objective-C?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I believe `- [NSDate timeIntervalSince1970]` is what you want.  Jan 1, 1970 is the date of the Unix epoch.

Comment: (long)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]]

Comment: OP is asking how to convert *an NSDate*, not necessarily the current date

Answer (score 50):

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval ti = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
```

`NSTimeInterval` is typedefed as a double, defined in seconds.  If you want it in integer form, just  cast the result to a long and use that instead, but this gives more precision.

Answer (score 10):

I like properties.

```
NSDate.date.timeIntervalSince1970;
```