# Timestamp conversions

Tags: ios, objective-c, timestamp, nsdateformatter

I am making an app and I am fetching the feed from Twitter. The feed returns the createAt value (when a tweet was created) in this type of format:

```
 "Mon Jun 24 14:27:26 +0000 2013"
```

How can I convert it into a timestamp value like this one?

```
 1372070724625
```

Comment: What is "1372070724625"?

Comment: It's a timestamp value which I get from Facebook API, but I was hoping I could be able to convert the twitter value to this one, because I have a library that converts it to "a few minutes ago", "30 minutes ago" and etc.

Comment: And I dont think it's a duplicate. The other post convert the value I wrote into another type of value from the one I am aiming to achieve.

Comment: What is the epoch for the timestamp? Use NSDateFormatter to convert the original string to an `NSDate`. Then use one of the `timeInterval` methods on `NSDate` to get the desired timestamp.

Comment: Martin below answered my question. Also I found some help on the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023264/how-to-convert-nsdate-into-unix-timestamp-in-objective-c-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output of

```
$ TZ=GMT date -r 1372070724
Mo 24 Jun 2013 10:45:24 GMT
```

I would guess that `1372070724625` is the number of milliseconds since the epoch.
So you should convert your string to `NSDate *date` using a `NSDateFormatter`, and then

```
long long timeStamp = (long long)([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get the logic behind timestamps and formatting know.