# How to send NSDate with a certain date format as NSNumber? i.e convert NSDate to NSDate with another format?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsnumber

I have two user selected dates: startDate and endDate. They are NSDate instances and I have to send them as parameters as `NSNumber`s. How can I convert them to NSNumber with seconds?

Comment: You mean NStimeInterval? then from there you can format the date

Comment: You shouldn't send raw date, because than you'll have problems with different time zones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) First, get the date in `MM/dd/yyyy` format:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
```

2) get string date and remove '/' from it:

```
NString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NString *finalStr = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];
```

3) Use `NSNumberFormatter` from converting `NSString` to `NSNumber`:

```
NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
f.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
NSNumber *myNumber = [f numberFromString: finalStr];
```

Hope, this is what you want!

Answer (score 3):

Use below code :

```
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
// set format however you want
[formatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy"];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSNumber *num1 = @([string intValue]);
NSLog(@"%@",num1);
```

Comment: I tried. It is taking the date as string in the form @"22/01/2016", but then when taken as int there is only 22 (int).

Comment: ' NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            dateFormat =SHORT_DATE_FORMAT;
            [formatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
            self.stringfr = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
            self.startDate  = @([self.stringfr intValue]);'

Comment: I hope I answered the way you expected.

Comment: Yes, exactly. only 22 out of string @"22/01/2016".

Comment: Let me check once

Comment: Check my edited answer I'm getting exactly what you want

Comment: sorry to say no. I think I should use NSTimeInterval.

Comment: Thank You for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a timestamp format 
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval ti = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
[How to convert NSDate into Unix timestamp in Objective C/iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023264/how-to-convert-nsdate-into-unix-timestamp-in-objective-c-iphone)

Thanks,